# Why does the Windows battery report show that there is negative power in my battery?

Tags: windows-10, laptop, battery

My Windows 10 laptop reported "no battery" this morning, and the Windows Battery report I generated reported a battery capacity of -1 mWh. After some charging, Windows recognized the battery again. What happened? How did Windows assign a negative amount of power to the battery?

The battery has at no point been disconnected from the laptop, and has only been charged with the correct Lenovo charger.

[image]

Comment: -1 is often used to mean “no value” in integer data fields. The battery controller could’ve malfunctioned.

Answer (score 1):

> After some charging, Windows recognized the battery again. What
> happened? How did Windows assign a negative amount of power to the
> battery?

Probably just a fluke in the measurement as the battery was very low.

Charge it properly to resolve this issue.

**(1) Reset the battery.**

Turn off the computer, plug in the AC Adapter, charge fully.
Unplug the AC adapter, turn on the computer, use it until it gets to 10 % or so.
Now charge it fully again.

**(2) Use Lenovo Vantage Battery Threshold Management.**

Run Vantage, Power Settings, Threshold Management.  Set to 80% for always or almost always plugged into AC.

Do not run the computer always plugged in at 100% charge.

80% is the generally accepted level for always plugged in.

Answer (score 1):

Windows interacts with battery controller using well-defined
protocols, for example the
[UEFI battery charging protocol](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/bringup/uefi-battery-charging-protocol).

Your battery apparently didn't have enough power for this communication,
so Windows decided that there was none.

When you charged up the battery, this worked because it's handled by the
hardware and doesn't require any protocol.

Once the battery had some power, it answered Windows and was detected.

The negative value was probably because the battery has a bit more
more power storage available than 100%. You were using up this
last reserve, so once you used up 101% of the rated power,
the number returned by the battery was `-1`.